# Extracting phrase n-grams from a sentence corresponding to the main verb

Tags: python, graph, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on a project which needs me to extract similarity between sentences. So given a sentence, I need the phrase n-gram of that sentence, which is 'a combination of the main verb and the noun phrase left and right of the verb'. Any idea how to extract this? I am given the dependency and constituency parse trees of the sentence. I am using Python.

```
Sample Sentence: My dog also likes eating sausage.
Constituency Parse Tree:
ROOT
(S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (NP (NN sausage)))))
    (. .)))

Dependency Graph:
nmod:poss(dog-2, My-1)
nsubj(likes-4, dog-2)
advmod(likes-4, also-3)
root(ROOT-0, likes-4)
xcomp(likes-4, eating-5)
dobj(eating-5, sausage-6)
```

Main verb : likes

Left Noun Phrase(NP) : My dog

Right Noun Phrase : sausage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Stanford OpenIE](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html)? Or, for that matter, any OpenIE system ([Ollie](https://knowitall.github.io/ollie/) / ReVerb / etc.).

**Minimal usage (via [Simple CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/simple.html)):**

`new Sentence("My dog also likes eating sausage.").openieTriples();`

**Pipeline/server usage:**

create a CoreNLP pipeline, and set the annotators to `tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,depparse,natlog,openie`. Then, the Open IE triples should be keyed on `RelationTripleAnnotation.class` key of a sentence.

**Try it out at [corenlp.run](http://corenlp.run)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer!